# Undefined symbol during link using libssh

Tags: c++, c, ssh, openssh, libssh

I am using libssh to accomplish connectivity between two systems, the ssh server is redhat, and the client is CentOS.

My code compiles and links just fine, except, at runtime I keep seeing this,

```
[1] libssh 0.5.5 (c) 2003-2010 Aris Adamantiadis (aris@0xbadc0de.be) Distributed under the LGPL, please refer to COPYING file for information about your rights, using threading threads_noop
[2] Nonblocking connection socket: 4
[2] Socket connecting, now waiting for the callbacks to work
[1] Socket connection callback: 1 (0)
[1] SSH server banner: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
[1] Analyzing banner: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
[1] We are talking to an OpenSSH client version: 5.3 (50300)
[2] Received SSH_KEXDH_REPLY
[2] SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
[2] Received SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS
./sshclient: symbol lookup error: ./sshclient: undefined symbol: ssh_pki_import_privkey_file
```

The code looks like this,

```
int main()
{
    ssh_session my_ssh_session;
    ssh_key *pubkey,*privkey;
    int verbosity = SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL;
    int port = 5022,rc;
    char username[20];

    strcpy(username,"yoda"); //assigned a user name
    my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
    if (my_ssh_session == NULL)
            exit(-1);
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, "XX.XX.XX.XX");
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, username);

    rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);
    if(rc != SSH_OK){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting to host: %s\n",ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));
            exit(-1);
    }
    rc = ssh_pki_import_privkey_file("/home/yoda/keys/id_rsa",NULL,NULL,NULL,privkey);
    if(rc != SSH_OK){
            fprintf(stderr, "Custom Message: Private Key unacceptable.\n");
            exit(-1);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Custom Message: Here now.\n");
    rc = ssh_userauth_publickey(my_ssh_session, NULL, *privkey);
    if(rc == SSH_AUTH_ERROR){
            fprintf(stderr, "Custom Message: A serious error has occured during authentication.\n");
            exit(-1);
    }
    if(rc == SSH_AUTH_DENIED){
            fprintf(stderr, "Custom Message: Unacceptable key or method.\n");
            exit(-1);
    }
    if(rc == SSH_AUTH_PARTIAL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Custom Message: Partially authenticated user.\n");
            exit(-1);
    }
    ssh_key_free(*pubkey);
    ssh_key_free(*privkey);
    ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
    ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
    return(0);
}
```

I know there are a bunch of problems with this code but at this point, I am experimenting with this library for the first time and more concerned with getting it to work. Any insight into whats going on would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks more like a compilation problem - can you post the commands you use to compile your code?

Comment: gcc -o sshclient sshRS.c -L/home/rs/libssh/lib -lssh -I/home/rs/libssh/include

Answer (score -1):

libssh 0.5 is out of maintenance. You should use libssh 0.6. If I remember correctly ssh_pki_import_privkey_file() is only available with libssh 0.6 ...